# Rails 5, modelo todos los campos en mayusculas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

En ASP NET MVC puedo crear una librería de clases donde tengo clases de ayuda para diferentes situaciones (conversión de fechas, cifrado, etc.), pero tengo una en específico que recibe mi modelo y recorre las propiedades y las que son tipo `String` las pasa a mayúsculas, de tal forma que yo hago algo así:

```
ClientesLogica.Save(Helpers.ViewModelToUpper(model));
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer algo parecido en Rails, y no tener que hacerlo campo por campo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La lógica la puedes poner en distintos lugares, dependiendo el fin específico.

Por ejemplo, si quieres que los valores se modifiquen antes de guardarse en la base de datos, lo harías directamente en tu modelo:

```
class ViewModel < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :to_upper

  private
  def to_upper
    attributes.keys.each do |attribute|
      self[attribute].try(:upcase!)
    end
  end
end
```

De esta forma los campos serán cambiados a mayúsculas cada vez que se guarde/actualice el registro en la base de datos.

Si lo piensas utilizar para más de un modelo, pudes agregar el método en la clase `ApplicationRecord`:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  private
  def to_upper
    attributes.keys.each do |attribute|
      self[attribute].try(:upcase!)
    end
  end
end

class ViewModel < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :to_upper
end
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias. lo voy a probar.!

Comment: Excelenteeeee... funciono perfecto... solo tengo ahora un problema con la validacion uniqueness,

Comment: solo tengo ahora un problema con la validacion uniqueness, con el to_upper marca error, al meter otra marca con la misma descripcion, si desactivo el to_upper y lo intento asi sin convertir a mayusculas, si funciona la validacion uniqueness 

<a href="http://s304.photobucket.com/user/leviatanMX/media/33367588_10214700046322537_6642101051350581248_n_1.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i304.photobucket.com/albums/nn178/leviatanMX/33367588_10214700046322537_6642101051350581248_n_1.jpg" border="0" alt=" photo 33367588_10214700046322537_6642101051350581248_n_1.jpg"/></a>

Comment: @LeonardoVelazquez Esto se debe a que el método `to_upper` se ejecuta **antes** de guardar el registro, pero no al momento de realizar la validación. Para que el método se ejecute antes de validar, utiliza `before_validation` en  lugar de `before_create`. Puedes ver todos los _callbacks_ disponibles para ActiveRecord [aquí](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks).

Comment: Hola que tal, ya quedo solucionado...  agregando unos parametros a UNIQUENESS

class Brand < ApplicationRecord
    before_save :to_upper

    validates :nombre, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, presence: true, length: {in: 4..40}           
    
    has_many :equipments
end